# Max Request Body does not work if the App is upgraded from 3.1 to 6.0 Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I had my application built on net core 3.1 then i upgraded the app to 3.1 to 6.0 for that i followed the step given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

After upgrading the app. i wanted to increase the request size limit for the some actions as i wanted to pass the large files.

for the i have added below to the program.cs file

```
    builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
    });
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
        options.MaxRequestBodyBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    });

    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // if don't set default value is: 128 MB
         options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    });
```

And this works fine for project which is built directly on 6.0 But as my project is upgraded to 6.0 same does not work for me.
I get 413 error that request entity is too big.

I tried it with the simple app with a form with file upload option and this issue can be regerated each time.

[image: Error i get when i make a call with ajax]

Is it something about the maxrequest size changed on the 6.0 where an upgraded app can not use that funtionality?

I tried finding any documentation about it but could not.

Comment: Are you actually using Kestrel, though? If this is in production then your program is likely running under IIS or HTTP.SYS, not Kestrel.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the other code. Yes, I have added the setting for the IIS as well. 

The issue is that it works fine for the app which is directly built on 6.0 
and does not work on the app which is upgraded to 6.0

Comment: You shouldn't be setting `options.MaxRequestBodyBufferSize` - that setting doesn't limit requests, it's there to protect your server from excessive memory usage - or to improve performance when large uploads need to be processed in-memory without paging or disk-based buffering. Don't touch it.

Comment: The max size is usually set in the Server OS and cannot be changed in code.

Comment: It is a sample project where I added all the possible solutions. to check if that makes any difference. But so far no luck. 
@jdweng Net core provides an option to set it from the Program.cs file directly.

Comment: An application cannot override a OS max parameter.  The OS will take preference.  Normally servers when limiting sizes of uploads will set Max at 10MB (but could be larger).

Comment: Got your point but I have tried other apps which work fine on the same server with higher file sizes. So, don't think the OS max parameter is an issue here. I have found a way around I have mentioned below but I would still like to know a better solution if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going a lot of back and forth.
The solution to this issue was to create a new project on net core 6.0 and shift my whole code to the new project.

Hope this helps others if anyone faces the same issue.
I still think there could be a better solution but till then this should do the work.